# Publishing application for specific duration

Tags: ios

I am first time developing an application which will have licensing to iPhone Application,

Our requirement is to develop an application that will have a license key and a subscription period, say 1 Month, 6 months, 1 Year.. Etc.

Once the subscription period is over user should not be able to reinstall the application without new subscription and license key, even if he/she has uninstalled the application.

How can this be done?

Comment: An option is to store info about user on your server and check subscription status every time the app is launched.

Comment: But then how we can give ne subscription and key with some subscription charges?

Comment: Obviously with using In-App purschases

Answer (score 4):

You could use a Non-Renewing Subscription in app purchase, This is the description in iTunes Connect : *Non-Renewing Subscriptions allow the sale of services with a limited duration. Non-Renewing Subscriptions must be used for In-App Purchases that offer time-based access to static content. Examples include a one week subscription to voice guidance feature within a navigation app or an annual subscription to online catalog of archived video or audio.*

or you could use a Auto-Renewable Subscription:
*Auto-renewable Subscriptions allow the user to purchase updating and dynamic content for a set duration of time. Subscriptions renew automatically unless the user opts out, such as magazine subscriptions.*

Comment: +1, this is indeed the way to offer subscription content on iOS. 
Note that the app itself will not be controlled by this- just the content controlled by the In-App Purchase.

Comment: @gearheadalex: In that case should I go with Non-Renewing Subscription in app purchase as I want to provide limited period subscription to entire application??

Comment: @ShitalTiwari, yes- in a fashion. 
You can't block access to the application itself, or remove it from the iOS device- but if you design the application to make it where it requires the subscription to access anything inside the app, that's as far as they'll get.
For example, a newspaper app with an expired subscription would still be able to be launched on the device, but the newspaper wouldn't be able to be read.

Comment: Thank you guys for the up votes, @ShitalTiwari I am trying to get accepted to ask questions again, if you think this is the correct answer could you please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative way:**

You have to do the subscription process through some website instead of in-app purchase.

Don't go with license key. Just provide login credentials to the user once he subscribed. User has to subscribe externally to use the application (by getting the login credentials by mail to him). If the subscription period over, then just don't allow him to login and ask him to meet administration using the given generic mail id (user has to subscribe again).

Comment: But then with external subscription how we can restrict user from reinstalling application?? Do we need to check each time in the central backend whether subscription period is valid or is it passed away?

Comment: @ShitalTiwari, once a user has purchased an application (even for free), you can't block them from reinstalling it or remove it from their device- as far as the App Store is concerned, it's theirs to use. You'd need to block the content inside of the application instead of the application itself.

Comment: @ShitalTiwari, you just block the login credentials instead of the application.